TV Spy Who Can Learn/Mimic Anything But Only for 90 Minutes?
There was a TV movie in the late 70's/early 80's about a (reluctant) spy who was somehow able to learn anything perfectly via a computer program (knowledge, language, mimicry), but he could only retain it for 90 minutes (I think), or some very limited amount of time.
I believe it was a CBS or NBC Saturday night movie of the week, shown in the USA.  Seems like it was intended to be a pilot, but obviously never got picked up.
Can anyone help me out with the name and cast, please?

I believe what you're searching for is the movie The Ultimate Impostor. It even had a guest appearance by Bobby Riggs!

Thank you so much for solving that!!  Been looking for an answer for years!
